# Show a curve in Qt5 using C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Now, I have geometry information of some curves, which are given with the following format.

```
<LineString><coordinates>-43.276042355627,-32.8022614460173,0.0 -43.9683944443137,-31.9135623685828,0.0 -44.4979806584518,-31.1926527722131,0.0</coordinates></LineString>
```

I would like to show them in my scene. I know I can do this by creating multiple `QGraphicsLineItem`s one by one. But is there any other easy way to do this, like one curve item?

Comment: you could use a qgraphicspathitem, on the other hand your format causes confusion you could damage that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QGraphicsPathItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html) along with [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html).
Reimplement the [QGraphicsPathItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html), add a method that receives your original points. Create a [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) and iterate over points. Use [moveTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#moveTo-1) on the first point and [lineTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#lineTo-1) for the next points. Then call [setPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html#setPath) of [QGraphicsPathItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html) to redraw the new curve.